# Fine-tuning BERT For Sequence Classification on sentiment140 dataset gives very POOR results

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, classification, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm using :

- [sentiment140](https://www.kaggle.com/kazanova/sentiment140) dataset
- [BertTokenizerFast](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.15.0/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertTokenizerFast) for text tokenization
- [TFBertForSequenceClassification](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.15.0/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.TFBertForSequenceClassification) for text classification

And I want to **fine-tune the** model (`TFBertForSequenceClassification`) on the dataset (`sentiment140`).

When doing so, the performances of my model are really bad.

With 10K tweets (~1h training) :

- ROC AUC score :  0.131
- Average Precision score :  0.325

With 1M tweets (~9h training) :

- ROC AUC score :  0.883
- Average Precision score :  0.822

The notebook run is available in [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/clementfleury/oc-p7/log?scriptVersionId=86383932).

I must be missing something obvious, but I really can't find what... Is it "just" an amount of training data problem ? Or am I not using the right parameters / metrics / optimizer ?

This is basically my code :

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

# Maths modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

# Load data from CSV
df = pd.read_csv(
    "../input/sentiment140/training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv",
    names=["target", "id", "date", "flag", "user", "text"],
    encoding="ISO-8859-1",
)

# Drop useless columns
df.drop(columns=["id", "date", "flag", "user"], inplace=True)


# Replace target values with labels
df.target.replace(
    {
        0: "NEGATIVE",
        2: "NEUTRAL",
        4: "POSITIVE",
    },
    inplace=True,
)

# And back to binary values
df.target.replace(
    {
        "NEGATIVE": 0,
        "POSITIVE": 1,
    },
    inplace=True,
)


# Sample data for development
TEXT_SAMPLE_SIZE = 10000  # <= 0 for all

# Sample data
if TEXT_SAMPLE_SIZE > 0:
    df = df.groupby("target", group_keys=False).apply(
        lambda x: x.sample(
            n=int(TEXT_SAMPLE_SIZE / df["target"].nunique()), random_state=42
        )
    ).reset_index(drop=True)



# Bert Tokenizers
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast

BERT_MODEL = "bert-base-uncased"

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL, do_lower_case=True)

input_ids = np.asarray([tokenizer(sent, padding="max_length", truncation=True)["input_ids"] for sent in tqdm(df.text)])
attention_mask = np.asarray([tokenizer(sent,padding="max_length",truncation=True)["attention_mask"] for sent in tqdm(df.text)])
token_type_ids = np.asarray([tokenizer(sent,padding="max_length",truncation=True)["token_type_ids"] for sent in tqdm(df.text)])



from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# Train-test split
(
    texts_train,
    texts_test,
    input_ids_train,
    input_ids_test,
    attention_mask_train,
    attention_mask_test,
    token_type_ids_train,
    token_type_ids_test,
    labels_train,
    labels_test,
) = train_test_split(
    df.text.values,
    input_ids,
    attention_mask,
    token_type_ids,
    df.target.values,
    test_size=0.2,
    stratify=df.target.values,
    random_state=42,
)



from transformers import TFBertForSequenceClassification
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import BinaryAccuracy


# Define NN model
print("Defining model...")
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    BERT_MODEL, num_labels=2
)

# compile NN network
print("Compiling model...")
model.compile(
    loss=BinaryCrossentropy(),
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=2e-5), # Value recommended by the Bert team
    metrics=BinaryAccuracy(),
)

# fit NN model
print("Fitting model...")
model.fit(
    [input_ids_train, attention_mask_train, token_type_ids_train],
    labels_train,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=8,
    validation_split=0.2,
    callbacks=[
        EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=2),
    ],
    workers=4,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
)

print(model.summary())


# Get predictions
y_pred = model.predict([input_ids_test, attention_mask_test, token_type_ids_test])
y_pred_proba = [float(x[1]) for x in tf.nn.softmax(y_pred.logits)]
y_pred_label = [0 if x[0] > x[1] else 1 for x in tf.nn.softmax(y_pred.logits)]


# Evaluate the model
from sklearn.metrics import (
    confusion_matrix,
    roc_auc_score,
    average_precision_score,
)

print("Confusion Matrix : ")
print(confusion_matrix(labels_test, y_pred_label))

print("ROC AUC score : ", round(roc_auc_score(labels_test, y_pred_proba), 3))

print("Average Precision score : ", round(average_precision_score(labels_test, y_pred_proba), 3))
```

With this, I get these logs while training :

```
Defining model...

All model checkpoint layers were used when initializing TFBertForSequenceClassification.

Some layers of TFBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['classifier']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.

Compiling model...
Fitting model...
Epoch 1/10

[...]

[==============================] - 5756s 72ms/step - loss: 0.4057 - binary_accuracy: 0.8482 - val_loss: 0.4579 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8421
Model: "tf_bert_for_sequence_classification"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bert (TFBertMainLayer)       multiple                  109482240 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_37 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
=================================================================
Total params: 109,483,778
Trainable params: 109,483,778
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

And these classification performances :

```
Confusion Matrix : 
[[17631 82369]
[ 415 99585]]
ROC AUC score :  0.883
Average Precision score :  0.822
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what is the expected performance with 1K tweets?

Comment: Well, it should at least be better than random guess, I expect ;)
So Average Precision and ROC AUC should be at least 0.5

Comment: I think learning rate is a common issue that causes abnormal behavior of bert. What learning rate are you using? Try 3e-6.

Comment: @namespace-Pt : that's an issue I had anticipated, and I used the recommended value by the Bert team : `optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=2e-5), # Value recommended by the Bert team` (cf. code in my question :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should try using BERTweet - as a base model it should improve the performance.
`BERT_MODEL = "vinai/bertweet-base"`

Secondly I personally am using Pytorch:
Here is the implementation which I used for my use-case:

````
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, \
                         AutoTokenizer, \
                         TrainingArguments, \
                         Trainer,\
                         pipeline
from transformers.data.data_collator import DataCollatorWithPadding

import torch
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support, \
                            accuracy_score, \
                            classification_report


train_texts = train_df.text.tolist()
val_texts = val_df.text.tolist()
train_encodings = tokenizer(train_texts, truncation=True, padding='max_length')
val_encodings = tokenizer(val_texts, truncation=True, padding='max_length')
class SentiDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

train_dataset = SentiDataset(train_encodings, train_df.label.tolist())
eval_dataset = SentiDataset(val_encodings, val_df.label.tolist())


def compute_metrics(pred, id2label):
    """
    Compute metrics for Trainer
    """
    labels = pred.label_ids
    preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)

    return get_metrics(preds, labels, id2label)


def get_metrics(preds, labels, id2label):
    ret = {}
    f1s, precs, recalls = [], [], []

    for i, cat in id2label.items():
        cat_labels, cat_preds = labels == i, preds == i
        precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(
            cat_labels, cat_preds, average='binary', zero_division=0,
        )

        f1s.append(f1)
        precs.append(precision)
        recalls.append(recall)

        ret[cat.lower()+"_f1"] = f1
        ret[cat.lower()+"_precision"] = precision
        ret[cat.lower()+"_recall"] = recall

    _, _, micro_f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(
        labels, preds, average="micro"
    )
    ret["micro_f1"] = micro_f1
    ret["macro_f1"] = torch.Tensor(f1s).mean()
    # ret["macro_precision"] = torch.Tensor(precs).mean()
    # ret["macro_recall"] = torch.Tensor(recalls).mean()

    # ret["acc"] = accuracy_score(labels, preds)

    return ret


epochs = 1
total_steps = (epochs * len(train_dataset)) // batch_size
warmup_steps = total_steps // 10

batch_size = 16
eval_batch_size = 32

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='.results',
    num_train_epochs=epochs,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=eval_batch_size,
    eval_steps=100,
    warmup_steps=warmup_steps,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    do_eval=False,
    save_strategy="epoch",
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    metric_for_best_model="eval_loss",
    greater_is_better=False,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    compute_metrics=lambda x: compute_metrics(x, id2label=id2label),
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator
)```
````

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using [BERTweet](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bertweet) ;)
What are your model's scores on the `sentiment140` dataset ?

Comment: Apart from not using the specificly designed and trained BERT model, is there something else I am doing wrong that would drag down my model's performances ?

Comment: I didn't try training on sentiment140, because it would have taken a lot of time. But it is created with distant supervision - so not necessarily all labels are correct. Maybe this was just maximum with that kind of data. Actually I would recommend just for benchmark trying out training on tweet_eval dataset (45k tweets). Try training your model and the one I suggested. maybe they would produce the same results. Here is the data https://huggingface.co/datasets/tweet_eval/viewer/sentiment/train

Answer (score 1):

Try with *num_labels=1* in:

```
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    BERT_MODEL, num_labels=2
)
```

You just need one class, the "sentiment class" (near 0 => negative, near 1=> positive).

I had the same problem and this worked for me (with 1K data).

Luc, (from OC.IA.p7 ;) )

Comment: I passed this project some time ago so I will not be able to test your solution, but it seems counter-intuitive and it is not how Huggingface officialy suggests to do : https://huggingface.co/blog/sentiment-analysis-python#3-training-the-model :/